# How do I draw a horizontal line without adding space

Tags: spacing, minipage

I divided my latex page into 3 using minipage.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t][9.8cm][t]{\textwidth} % 9.8cm is about 1/3 of A4 height
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

%\hrulefill

\begin{minipage}[t][9.8cm][t]{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

%\hrulefill

\begin{minipage}[t][9.8cm][t]{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I want to add horizontal lines between the minipage. However, when i do \hrulefill, it takes up space and forces the third minipage to go to a new page. How do I fix this? I don't want to shrink the height of minipage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your aim is to divide the page into three part for later cutting, with the rules serving as crop marks, you're better using lower level functions:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newlength{\onethird}
\setlength{\onethird}{0.33333\textheight}
\newcommand{\divider}{%
  \par\nobreak
  \vskip 0pt plus 100pt minus 100pt
  \hrule height0.05pt depth 0.05pt
  \nobreak
  \vskip 0pt plus 100pt minus 100pt
}

\flushbottom

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\vbox to\onethird{
\leaders\vrule\vfill\kern0pt % you'll use \vfill

\lipsum[1]

\leaders\vrule\vfill\kern0pt % you'll use \vfill
}

\divider

\vbox to\onethird{
\leaders\vrule\vfill\kern0pt % you'll use \vfill

\lipsum[1]

\leaders\vrule\vfill
}

\divider

\vbox to\onethird{
\leaders\vrule\vfill\kern0pt % you'll use \vfill

\lipsum[1]

\leaders\vrule\vfill
}

\end{document}
```

I used `\leaders\vrule\vfill` to produce something visible instead of blank space. Use normal spacing commands for filling each part of the sheet. The `\hrule` is 0.1 pt thick, so it's a hairline, suitable as a crop mark.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.32\paperheight` and insert some `\vfill` to distribute the vertical space between the mini pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t][.32\paperheight][t]{\textwidth} % 9.8cm is about 1/3 of A4 height
\lipsum[1]

\vfill

end 1st
\end{minipage}\\
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

\vfill
\begin{minipage}[t][.32\paperheight][t]{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\vfill

end 2nd
\end{minipage}\\
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

\vfill
\begin{minipage}[t][.32\paperheight][t]{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\vfill

end 3rd
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]